# Why does mysql client characterset differ depending on which linux user connects to mysql

Tags: mysql

If I am logged into my linux box as root and then connect to mysql on the command line, typing "\s" at the interactive prompt tells me that the Client characterset and Connection characterset are utf8. If I exit mysql, "su - bob", connect to mysql (as the same mysql user), then typing "\s" at the interactive prompt tells me that the Client characterset and the Connection characterset are latin1.

I looked for differences in root's environment from bob's environment that could be relevant and, when logged in as bob, I set those to the same values as they were for the root user and connected to mysql again - but I still see latin1.

Could someone explain what might be the factor here that is causing the difference?

Many Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

mysql client uses the LANG or LC_ALL local environment variables to set the client and connection character set. and if non of these variables are defined then the default character set is used which is latin1 I think.
So if root and bob user have different values for these env variables than connection and client character set will be different when you will connect from respective OS user.

Comment: root has LANG=POSIX, LC_ALL not set, LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 and bob has LANG=en_US.UTF-8, LC_ALL not set, LC_CTYPE not set. I tried setting these variables in the bob'b shell (and exporting) to the same as root's values before running the mysql client, but still I see latin1.